# First cell in active row during script execution

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the code below to view through a sheet, and change the first cell background to red if any other cells are red. What I would like, is to change the first cell in each row to red, only if that row contains a red cell. This code works through the spreadsheet, but only makes cell A1 red. How do I get it to affect the first cell of each row independently?

```
    function MakeRed(){
  var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = book.getActiveSheet();
  var first_column = "B";
  var first_row = 1;
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var last_column = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var active_row = 1;
  var range_input = sheet.getRange(1,1,last_row,last_column);
  var range_output = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var cell_colors = range_input.getBackgroundColors();
  var color = "#ff0000";
  var count = 0;

  for(var r = 0; r < cell_colors.length; r++) {
    for(var c = 0; c < cell_colors[0].length; c++) {
      if(cell_colors[r][c] == color) {
        count++;
        range_output.setBackground("#ff0000");
      } else {
        count--;
        if (count == 0) {
          range_output.setBackground("#ffffff");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you do the whole stuff in the array of background colors you already have instead of calling a spreadsheet service each time the condition is true.

Code becomes simpler because I used the indexOf array method in the condition

```
function MakeRed(){
  var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = book.getActiveSheet();
  var first_column = "B";
  var first_row = 1;
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var last_column = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var active_row = 1;
  var range_input = sheet.getRange(1,1,last_row,last_column);
  var range_output = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var cell_colors = range_input.getBackgroundColors();
  var color = "#ff0000";
  var count = 0;

  for(var r = 0; r < cell_colors.length; r++) {
    Logger.log(cell_colors[r].indexOf(color));// just to check, you can remove this of course ...
    if(cell_colors[r].indexOf(color)>-1) {
      count++;
      cell_colors[r][0]=color;
    } else {
      count--;
      if (count == 0) {
        cell_colors[r][0]="#ffffff";
      }
    }
  }
  range_input.setBackgroundColors(cell_colors);// update sheet colors
}
```

---

**EDIT :** I don't really understand the idea behind the "count" thing... it works the same way without it (code below) :

```
function MakeRed(){
  var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = book.getActiveSheet();
  var first_column = "B";
  var first_row = 1;
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var last_column = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var active_row = 1;
  var range_input = sheet.getRange(1,1,last_row,last_column);
  var range_output = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var cell_colors = range_input.getBackgroundColors();
  var color = "#ff0000";

  for(var r = 0; r < cell_colors.length; r++) {
    Logger.log(cell_colors[r].indexOf(color))
    if(cell_colors[r].indexOf(color)>-1) {
      cell_colors[r][0]=color;
    } else {
      cell_colors[r][0]="#ffffff";
    }
  }
  range_input.setBackgroundColors(cell_colors);// update sheet colors
}
```

**edit 2** : this version will reset col A to white if no other red cell is in the row

```
function MakeRed(){
  var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = book.getActiveSheet();
  var first_column = "B";
  var first_row = 1;
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var last_column = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var active_row = 1;
  var range_input = sheet.getRange(1,1,last_row,last_column);
  var range_output = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var cell_colors = range_input.getBackgroundColors();
  var color = "#ff0000";

  for(var r = 0; r < cell_colors.length; r++) {
    var rowWoColA = cell_colors[r].slice(1);
    if(rowWoColA.indexOf(color)>-1) {
      cell_colors[r][0]=color;
    } else {
      cell_colors[r][0]="#ffffff";
    }
  }
  range_input.setBackgroundColors(cell_colors);// update sheet colors
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the count was old code from the first person who was attempting to do this, he was simply incrementing a counter (code he found online). This is working well, only part that is not working, is if the background changes from red, the first column should clear but is not?

Comment: code updated, now I check the colors in all cells except cells in column A so it works as expected (I hope ;-)

Comment: They asked for the code to now check for whether the row had yellow, orange, or red and make the first cell change accordingly (with each color superseding next, so if there was yellow and orange orange would be the color of first cell, if red in row then red first cell).

Comment: Please post a new question, you'll have more chances to get a good answer... ( in a comment it looks like a request a dressed to me, that's not a good idea... I'm just a contributor :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change `var range_output = sheet.getRange("A1");` to the range you want edit.

You could do this in the loop:

```
for(var r = 0; r < cell_colors.length; r++) {
    for(var c = 0; c < cell_colors[0].length; c++) {
      if(cell_colors[r][c] == color) {
        count++;
        // Assuming you only want to change bg color of the first column on each row
        sheet.getRange(r,1).setBackground("#ff0000");
      } else {
        count--;
        if (count == 0) {
          sheet.getRange(r,1).setBackground("#ffffff");
        }
      }
    }
  }
```